# Eclipse ADT crashes when opening XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I have had a problem opening XML files in the Eclipse ADT for three days, and have not been able to find a solution that worked on Google.

Every time I try to open an XML file in Eclipse ADT, Eclipse closes without any error message. What can I do to view these files in Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse is officially been deprecated,  you should switch to Android Studio.  http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

Comment: But I don't want to switch to android studio, because eclipse ADT is best and my all projects are in it. Please give me solution. I have been using eclipse from past 3years it never happened to me, I have seen this problem first time. Please guys solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably won't get a solution, the fix is to switch to Android Studio, Eclipse is buggy and no longer supported. It is super easy to switch from Eclipse to Android Studio, so do it.

Comment: While I understand wanting to stick with what you're comfortable with and not making changes, I too would suggest switching to AndroidStudio, it would be bad practice to continue using a deprecated tool. The link that Tristan shared gives you everything you need to know about switching quickly and painlessly.

Comment: Regardless of all that, were you able to open the XML files fine before? What changed three days ago?

Comment: thanks you very much guys for reply. I'm gonna do that know.

Comment: Nothing changed it happened suddenly.

Comment: @varun good! Any issues ask and I'll help you out.

Comment: Hmm. Can you view the files in Notepad or anything else? Just curious, I wonder if it's a problem with the specific XML file, and not eclipse. Also, is this really *only* with XML files? Java files open fine?

Comment: Everything works fine except XML file opener

Comment: By the way I'm know switching to android studio anyway

Comment: My suspicion is that you downloaded an update to the platform files.  ...  Switching out of Eclipse is not what he asked about. Android Studio is not compatible with as many OS platforms as Eclipse.  It is incidentally very annoying to see a use ask a clear question, and instead get replies about changing his development process.